# Find days since last event pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame:

```
df12 = pd.DataFrame({'group_ids':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'dates':['2016-04-01','2016-04-20','2016-04-28','2016-04-05','2016-04-20','2016-04-29'],'event_today_in_group':[1,0,1,1,1,0]})


   group_ids      dates  event_today_in_group
0          1 2016-04-01                     1
1          1 2016-04-20                     0
2          1 2016-04-28                     1
3          2 2016-04-05                     1
4          2 2016-04-20                     1
5          2 2016-04-29                     0
```

I would like to compute an additional column that contains, for each group_ids, the number of days since the last time event_today_in_group was 1.

```
 group_ids      dates  event_today_in_group  days_since_last_event
0          1 2016-04-01                     1                      0
1          1 2016-04-20                     0                     19
2          1 2016-04-28                     1                     27
3          2 2016-04-05                     1                      0
4          2 2016-04-20                     1                     15
5          2 2016-04-29                     0                      9
```

Answer (score 8):

As I mentioned earlier, this will get you the non-cumulative difference between dates within each group:

```
df['days_since_last_event'] = df.groupby('group_ids')['dates'].diff().apply(lambda x: x.days)
```

In order to get a cumulative sum of this difference, based on whenever `event_today_in_group` changes, I propose using `shift` to get the value of the previous row, and then generating a cumulative sum, like so:

```
df['event_today_in_group'].shift().cumsum()
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    2.0
4    3.0
5    4.0
```

This gives us the second grouping value we need to get the cumulative sums. You could assign the above values to a new column, but if you're only using them for the calculation, then you can simply include them in the subsequent `groupby` operation like so:

```
df.loc[:, 'days_since_last_event'] = df.groupby(['group_ids', df['event_today_in_group'].shift().cumsum()])['days_since_last_event'].cumsum()
```

Result:

```
   group_ids      dates  event_today_in_group  days_since_last_event
0          1 2016-04-01                     1                    NaN
1          1 2016-04-20                     0                   19.0
2          1 2016-04-28                     1                   27.0
3          2 2016-04-05                     1                    NaN
4          2 2016-04-20                     1                   15.0
5          2 2016-04-29                     0                    9.0
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. However, I am not looking to difference with respect to the previous row in the group, rather I am trying to find the time difference when the last time the event occurred and the current date.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, I will revise the answer.

Comment: @SrikantChari when is the current date?

Comment: @piRSquared By current date, I meant for each date in the 'dates' column. For example, for group_ids =  1, and dates = '2016-04-28', the number of days since the last time the event occurred, event_today_in_group = 1, is 27 days.